# how to setState with fetch API on click button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm new to React and wanted to fetch API.The idea is: when I click a button then it should first change a state and then fetch data. Now is not working how I expected... when I click the button it displays data from 4 cites(because of init state) and then I click particular city (eg. Tampere) but after clicking nothing happens yet, when I click another button (eg Helsinki) it display me data from previous clicked button(Tampere city)....How to fix it? I use console.log for displaying data because it's just testing.
I'd appreciate if you can have a look at my components.
Thank you!

**App.js** and **DropBar.js**

````
------------------
//main component in App.js file

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cityId: '658225,655195,650225,634964&units=metric',
      multi: 'group'
    }
  }

  getWeather = ({ currentTarget }) => {
fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/${this.state.multi}?id=${this.state.cityId}&appid=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {

        this.setState({
          cityId: currentTarget.id,
          multi: currentTarget.value
        })
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MainLayout>
        <div className="App">Hello!</div>
        <DropBar getWeather={this.getWeather} />
      </MainLayout>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

------------------
//Buttons component in DropBar.js file

 const DropBar = (props) => {

  return (
    <form >
      <Button id="634964" value="weather" onClick={props.getWeather}>Click Tampere!</Button>
      <Button id="658225" value="weather" onClick={props.getWeather}>Click Helsinki!</Button>
      <Button id="655195" value="weather" onClick={props.getWeather}>Click Jyvaskila!</Button>
      <Button id="650225" value="weather" onClick={props.getWeather}>Click Kuopio!</Button>
      <Button
        id="658225,655195,650225,634964&units=metric"
        value="group"
        onClick={props.getWeather}
      >
        All kaupungit!
      </Button>
    </form>
  );

}

export default DropBar;```
````

Comment: fetching the data just takes time like all http requests, it is impossible to `first change a state and then fetch data` if you want to make state reflect the fetched data

Comment: `setState` is async. This means you cannot console log the updated values immediately after setting it. The update doesn't happen right away. If you console.log inside the render method, you will see the correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use setState callback

```
getWeather = ({ currentTarget }) => {
  this.setState({
    cityId: currentTarget.id,
    multi: currentTarget.value
  }, () => {
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/${this.state.multi}?id=${this.state.cityId}&appid=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  })
};
```

Comment: Great, after changes, as you suggested with code above, everything is working! Thank you to all.